# Допустимы ли в поле input (radio/checkbox), в атрибуте value русские буквы, предложения?

Tags: html, веб-программирование

**Пример кода**

```
<h3>Вы любите кофе или чай?</h3>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="question1_answer_1" name="menu" value="Я люблю кофе">Я люблю кофе
<!-- 
Или так? 
<input type="radio" name="question1_answer_1" name="menu" value="coffe">Я люблю кофе 
-->
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1_answer_1" name="menu" value="Я люблю чай">Я люблю чай
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Разумеется, тут можно писать текст"> Пример поля text<br>
</form>
```

Так как варианты ответа я пишу по русски, то я использую эти же фразы и в value.
В результате код становится более понятным, мне не надо вводить/запоминать/сопоставлять value="coffe" с Я люблю кофе. Становится меньше сущностей, меньше действий с кодом и бд.

Для чекбоксов и радиокнопок допустимо использовать русские буквы, предложения?
И это принято? Или принято только писать по английски?

Comment: Т.е. кириллица в остальных атрибутах `value=` вас не беспокоит, а только в radio/checkbox ?.) HTML-у без разницы что там в value. Однако для корректной работы всё же следует следить за языком и кодировкой страницы, а то мало ли что там у вас.

Comment: @stylok нет не беспокоит. В input type="text" часто пишут русский текст (что очевидно). 
А вот в radio и checkbox почему то часто используют английский, как я показал в примере. Страница на русском, кодировка русская, описание пункта на русском - Я люблю кофе, а вот value="coffe".
И такое во многих примерах.

Comment: Полагаю, что использование таких примеров — скорее наследие вырванных из чужого контекста кусков кода и обыкновенная лень переключения раскладок во время набора. Уверяю вас, что никакой разницы нет. Можете хоть иероглифы использовать.)